# Provisioning profile "app" has app ID "com.reactjs.native.example.app", which does not match the bundle ID

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-onesignal

I am using React Native with react-native-onesignal library. After following the installing docs I face this problem :

> Provisioning profile "app" has app ID "com.reactjs.native.example. app", which does not match the bundle ID "com.reactjs.native.example. app.OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension".

Comment: Have tried to automatically signing in xcode?

Comment: yes it failed too